# changing Instagram profile image

Tags: c#, api, instagram, sharp

I use the following code to change image my Instagram profile, but give the following error.

Error is:

```
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

Is anyone here to help me?
Thank.
I also use `InstagramApiSharp` for this.

```
OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
  byte[] picByte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(op.FileName);
  var result = await 
  ctx.api.AccountProcessor.ChangeProfilePictureAsync(picByte);
  if (result.Succeeded)
  {
    pic_box.ImageLocation = op.FileName;
  }
}
```

I use the following code but the image does not change again and no error message and no results

```
var picturePath = @"C:\Users\Rayehe\Desktop\had.jpg";
var pictureBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(picturePath);
var result = await ctx.api.AccountProcessor.ChangeProfilePictureAsync(pictureBytes);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
MessageBox.Show("New profile picture: " + result.Value.ProfilePicUrl);
}
else
{
MessageBox.Show("Error while changing profile picture: " + result.Info.Message);
}
```

Comment: what type of image file are you using (JPEG, GIF,...)? And also have you debugged to see at what line the problem occurs?

Comment: @alainlompo (JPEG) I use. Does it matter the format? NO.

Comment: It does as not all formats are accepted, but JPEG is. How about the error where does it happen exactly right by ReadAllBytes... or further down?

Comment: @alainlompo I did not get you.

Comment: Ok: I mean it would be great if you could put a break point in the code and debug in order to find out exactly what line produces the exception...

Comment: @alainlompo  Error is not running the program. When I use ( MessageBox.Show(result.Info.Message);) command. result is (Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.
)

Comment: @alainlompo I also use the second code I wrote above but the image doesn't change again and no error message at all. No results.